# select values based on condition on multiple columns for pandas dataframe in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Here is my dataframe dim

```
          var         types     count
0         var1       nominal      1
1         var2       ordinal      1
2         var3  quantitative      2
3         var4  quantitative      2
```

I want to get the dim["var"] where dim["types"] == quantitative and dim["count"] > 1. The result then is a list  [var3, var4]. 
When I am trying the following query:

```
print(dim["var"].where((dim["types"] =="quantitative") & (dim["count"] > 1)))
```

I am getting the following result:

```
0    NaN
1    NaN
2    NaN
3    NaN
```

I don't know how can I get the desired solution.

Comment: sorry updated the question.. as I was about to revise the question, my little one jumped over my laptop. :?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) with mask:

```
L = dim.loc[(dim["types"] =="quantitative") & (dim["count"] > 1), "var"].tolist()
print (L)
['var3', 'var4']
```

Your output is correct, because [`Series.where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html) convert where condition is `False` values to missing values:

```
print ((dim["types"] =="quantitative") & (dim["count"] > 2))
0    False
1    False
2    False
3    False
dtype: bool

print(dim["var"].where((dim["types"] =="quantitative") & (dim["count"] > 2)))
0    NaN
1    NaN
2    NaN
3    NaN
Name: var, dtype: object
```

So if use `==` in condition output is:

```
print ((dim["types"] =="quantitative") & (dim["count"] > 1))
0    False
1    False
2     True
3     True
dtype: bool

print(dim["var"].where((dim["types"] =="quantitative") & (dim["count"] > 1)))
0     NaN
1     NaN
2    var3
3    var4
Name: var, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `loc` accessor with your mask.

```
>>> (dim["types"] == "quantitative") & (dim["count"] > 1)
0    False
1    False
2     True
3     True
dtype: bool
```

Like this:

```
>>> dim.loc[(dim["types"] == "quantitative") & (dim["count"] > 1), 'var']
2    var3
3    var4
Name: var, dtype: object
```